# webpack-dev-middleware with create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack, create-react-app

in my react\node app i use webpack-dev-middleware and webpack-hot-middleware on the node side in order to get a bundle reload when files change in the client as well as reload server when server code changes(this is done with nodemon). so with one node cli command i run both the http server and serve static files with express static, getting auto-reload for both. 
we are now starting a little short-term app with create-react-app, what is the best way to get the same functionality with this boilerplate? configuring in the same way brings many errors. any best known methods\alternatives you guys know?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives, yes. Checkout my [hapi-react-hot-loader-example](https://github.com/codeBelt/hapi-react-hot-loader-example)